# Wix window service only copy exe file in installation folder not all dependencies

Tags: service, wix, window

I am new in wix and creating a window service. I have created my service and successfully added in window service but when I run it stopped due to error.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?define Name = "New Window Service" ?>
<?define Manufacturer = "GAT" ?>
<?define UpgradeCode = "{0d4fb541-bb66-4df8-bdab-893564e191fc}" ?>

<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs"
     xmlns:util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util"
       >
  <Product Id="*" Name="$(var.Name)" Manufacturer="$(var.Manufacturer)" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)"  Language="1033">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <Media Id="1" Cabinet="GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of [ProductName] is already installed. Setup will now exit." />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="ROOTDIRECTORY" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
          <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.Name)" />
        </Directory>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <Component Id="$(var.GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.TargetFileName)">
        <CreateFolder />
        <File Id="$(var.GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.TargetFileName)" Source="D:\Projects\GATAC\GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost\bin\Release\GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe" KeyPath="yes"  Vital="yes" />
        <File Id="GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe.config"
                                  Name="MyProduct.exe.config"
                                  Source="D:\Projects\GATAC\GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost\bin\Release\GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe.config"
                                  Vital="yes"
                                  KeyPath="no"
                                  DiskId="1" />
        <RemoveFile Id="ALLFILES" Name="*.*" On="both" />
        <util:XmlFile Id="ModifyServiceLocation" Action="setValue" ElementPath="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[\[]@name='DefaultConnection'[\]]/@connectionString" File="D:\Projects\GATAC\GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost\bin\Release\GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.exe.config" Value="Data Source=[DB_SERVER];Initial Catalog=[DB_DATABASE];User Id=[DB_USER];Pwd=[DB_PASSWORD]"/>

        <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller"
                        Type="ownProcess"
                        Name="GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost"
                        DisplayName="$(var.Name)"
                        Description="A Test Service that logs dummy text on an interval to a text file."
                        Start="auto"
                        ErrorControl="normal"
                        />
        <ServiceControl Id="ServiceInstaller"
                    Stop="both"
                    Remove="both"
                    Name="GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost"
                    Wait="yes" />
      </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>
    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
      <ComponentRef Id="$(var.GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.TargetFileName)" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
</Wix>
```

when I saw in installation folder of service there is only exe file so how to copy all dependencies of window service in this folder my code is following.When I copy files manually in installation folder it works.Do I need to harvest

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you need to include **ALL** files in your wxs as components you want to install.

If you have a few dependencies, you can just add them as File components yourself. If there are a lot of files consider using heat to generate the wxs file for you and you can copy the file elements into your wxs code. If the file dependencies may change frequently, consider using heat to always generate the wxs and include it as a linked file in your main installer project.

Ideally all your dependencies are being included in the GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost project's bin folder so you can just use $(var.GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir)DependencyFileName as the Source for the file.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer but I ma getting error when I use $(var.GAT.GATAC.ServiceLayer.WindowsServiceHost.TargetDir) "undefined preprocessor variable". I have already added reference of project in wix project as well

Comment: There should be in the output window when you build a candle.exe and then a LOT of defines. You can search this window for "TargetDir" and it should show you -d<ProjectName>.TargetDir=Path for the GAT.GATAC... project. Maybe it is just a small typo.